# how to add text title in .avi video in android usng ffmpeg command

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

i want to **add text** in **.avi videos** in android application.

so,
I  searched on Google but i didn't get any solution for this problem  please try to help me.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution listed here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/0T8-9Cc96qc

Or a cut/paste answer is

Step #1: Put the VideoView/SurfaceView/TextureView inside a RelativeLayout

Step #2: Put your "transparent text" (whatever you think that is)
inside the same RelativeLayout, as a later child (e.g., later in the
XML)

Step #3: Conditionally hide and show the "transparent text" as you see fit

Comment: thanks for reply but i need to add text on .avi video using ffmpeg command then i try this command ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf drawtext="fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSans.ttf: text='YOUR TEXT HERE':fontcolor=red@1.0:fontsize=70:x=00: y=40" -y output.mp4  but it gives error Error Opening Filters. so please help me